# Commit into TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
            /command:commit /path:******\trunk\dotnet /notempfile /closeonend
            1000

the code above pops up a window asking for "entering a message, selecting the changed content and then clicking OK and again clicking OK again after the process completes"

I would be extremely thankful if anyone can suggest how to avoid the above said process if commit is done using cruise control (config file).

thanks. 
**pratap**

Answer (score 2):

It's not CruiseControl that does the commit - it's just calling TortoiseSVN to trigger a GUI wrapper over a Subversion action. So to execute the commit as a silent activity (i.e. with no GUI) you simply need to replace the invocation of TortoiseSVN with a call to 'svn commit' and provide the appropriate parameters.

Svn help [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re06.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are automating SVN actions, you should be using a [command-line client](http://www.sliksvn.com), not TortoiseSVN.  Hit that link to download a client, and see the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [tortoiseproc.exe here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html).

> "You can also specify the /logmsg
>   switch to pass a predefined log
>   message to the commit dialog."

you may also want to append your **/closeonend** to be **/closeonend:1** to prevent the extra confirmation click step.  The switch values are also described on the documentation page.

I do not use crusecontrol but I do this sucesfully from a command file that I use to commit and publish my asp.net site.

Comment: I will add that the value of tortoise svn is that it prompts you to add a comment on the revision you are committing.  Which would generally be good practice.  And has has proved super handy for me a number of times.